# Change parent block background when child input is checked(vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to the world of coding, and would be very grateful for an advise or  any idea. I was wondering if it is possible to change color of current parent block background(.checkbox-container), when child input is checked. And the main problem is that I have multiple blocks with inputs, and require to change background color only to current block, not to all? As I understood there is no pure css solution without mark-up change, but this is not my case. Could someone please give any idea how that could be done in vanilla js?

Here is the link to fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/william_eduards/r4jxvuz5/4/

and visual code example here:

```css
.checkbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: #E8EBF0;
  border: 1px solid #E8EBF0;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dimensional-container checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="snapchat" class="checkbox-container__snapchat" id="snapchat">
  <label for="snapchat">snapchat</label>
</div>
<div class="dimensional-container checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="facebook" class="checkbox-container__facebook" id="facebook">
  <label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
</div>
<div class="dimensional-container checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hangouts" class="checkbox-container__hangouts" id="hangouts">
  <label for="hangouts">hangouts</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find all `input` using `querySelectorAll`.
- Loop over all input and `addEventListener`
- check if the elment is checked or not using `e.target.checked`, If it is checked change its parent `e.target.parentElement` background `style`.

I've used `red`, you can select color on your own.

```js
const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

allInputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      e.target.parentElement.style.background = "#ff0000";
    } else {
      e.target.parentElement.style.background = "#E8EBF0";
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.checkbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: #E8EBF0;
  border: 1px solid #E8EBF0;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dimensional-container checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="snapchat" class="checkbox-container__snapchat" id="snapchat">
  <label for="snapchat">snapchat</label>
</div>
<div class="dimensional-container checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="facebook" class="checkbox-container__facebook" id="facebook">
  <label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
</div>
<div class="dimensional-container checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hangouts" class="checkbox-container__hangouts" id="hangouts">
  <label for="hangouts">hangouts</label>
</div>
```